# how to install boost-devel 1.59 in CentOS7‏

Tags: boost

I want to install boost-devel 1.59 in centos7, but the default repo has only 1.53, so I have to compile it from the source code.

I have download 1.59 from web page, and use ./bootstrap.sh and ./b2 install to install the boost 1.59.

But when I want install other packages such as CGAL-devel, it tells me that I donnot install boost-devel 1.59, so I wonder how to install boost-devel?

Thanks.

Comment: Just copy the whole `boost` folder to `/usr/include`. It worked for me.

Comment: copying `boost` folder to `/user/include` got me partly there, but then I got compiler errors that so files were missing from /user/lib64. Not sure how to generate the `.so` files

Answer (score 6):

Got boost 1.59 version installed in CentOS 7 with the below commands:

```
sudo wget http://repo.enetres.net/enetres.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/enetres.repo
```

Download the lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm from the below link:
ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/Mandriva/official/2010.0/x86_64/media/main/release/lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm

Install the RPM:

```
sudo rpm -ivh lib64icu42-4.2.1-1mdv2010.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Install the required boost library version:

```
sudo yum install boost-devel
```

That's it. Have a great day!

rpm link:
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)

Comment: wget link now broken

Answer (score 4):

Download Boost Library from:

https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.gz

Unzip, Bootstrap and Install

```
tar -xzf boost_1_76_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_76_0
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost
./b2 install --prefix=/opt/boost --with=all
```

Comment: Bintray went out of service since May 2021 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362965/boost-binary-forbidden-downloaded-via-hunter/67370439#67370439

Comment: Updated with new links. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to install it on CentOS 6.7. Not sure is it possible to install CentOS 6 packages to CentOS 7.

I found the solution in this blog post:
http://vicendominguez.blogspot.com/2014/04/boost-c-library-rpm-packages-for-centos.html

Try to install boost from this repo: http://repo.enetres.net/enetres.repo

```
sudo wget http://repo.enetres.net/enetres.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/enetres.repo
sudo yum install boost-devel
```

Comment: This did not work on the Docker centos:7 image. Long error output including, ```Error: Package: libboost_log1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)```

Comment: I have the same problem as @HaraldNordgren