# Boost binary forbidden (downloaded via hunter)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, bintray

I am trying to use cmake to compile and noticed the boost binary link is not available (forbidden). Is there a workaround to this?

```
[ 25%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'Boost'
-- verifying file...
       file='/home/op/.hunter/_Base/Download/Boost/1.66.0/075d0b4/boost_1_66_0.7z'
-- SHA1 hash of
    /home/op/.hunter/_Base/Download/Boost/1.66.0/075d0b4/boost_1_66_0.7z
  does not match expected value
    expected: '075d0b43980614054b1f1bafd189f863bba6600e'
      actual: 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'
-- File already exists but hash mismatch. Removing...
-- Downloading...
   dst='/home/op/.hunter/_Base/Download/Boost/1.66.0/075d0b4/boost_1_66_0.7z'
   timeout='none'
-- Using src='https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.7z'
-- Retrying...
-- Using src='https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.7z'
-- Retry after 5 seconds (attempt #2) ...
-- Using src='https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.7z'
-- Retry after 5 seconds (attempt #3) ...
-- Using src='https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.7z'
-- Retry after 15 seconds (attempt #4) ...
```

relevant config:

```
hunter_config(CURL VERSION ${HUNTER_CURL_VERSION} CMAKE_ARGS HTTP_ONLY=ON CMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=OFF CMAKE_USE_LIBSSH2=OFF CURL_CA_PATH=none)
hunter_config(Boost VERSION 1.66.0)
```

Answer (score 14):

A workaround that fixed the issue for me was to manually download boost_1_66_0.7z from https://www.boost.org/ and place it under $HOME/.hunter/_Base/Download/Boost/1.66.0/075d0b4/

Comment: this is the only way working as of now , server hosting at bintray.com is returning Forbidden! instead of files so we have to download  it manually from other sources  and place file into the folder

Comment: It took me some digging:  https://boostorg.jfrog.io/ui/native/main/release/1.66.0/source/

Answer (score 5):

Bintray went out of service per May 1st, 2021¹:

https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2021/02/250813.php

> Thank you for supporting JFrog through your use of Bintray. We are and continue to be a community-focused company, and in the spirit of transparency weâ€™re giving you advance notice that as of May 2021, we will be sunsetting Bintray.

Boost downloads are available here now:

https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost//2021/04/251468.php

> Bintray is â€œsunsettingâ€ on the 1st of May. At that time, you will
> be unable to download boost releases from there. Before that time,
> their service will be occasionally interrupted. The web site has been
> updated, all the download links now refer to
> https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/
> Example: Instead
> of downloading from:
> https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.gz
>
> You should download from:
> https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.gz
>
> This applies to all releases from 1.63.0 onward (The pre-1.63 releases
> are still hosted at SourceForge)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is using the working version of hunter, with the latest version of CMake, I have made a pull request with this solution, it is working

Check it here https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/pull/2413/files